# Python Mock Patch patches a used module for submodule under test and every other imported submodule in the submodule under test

Tags: python, unit-testing, monkeypatching

Sorry for the rather confusing title, but find it really hard to get to a crisp headline.

**My Problem:**

I have a submodule under test lets call it `backend`.  And I use `random.choice` in `backend`. I patch it in my test and that works. It is patched. `backend` imports `pymongo`to do some database stuff and pymongo uses `random.choice`as well for selecting the right server in `core.py`.

Somehow my patch of `backend.random.choice` also is used for `backend.pymongo.random.choice`. I am not sure why. Is that the correct behavior? And if it is, what is the way to get around that? Preferebly without changing any code in backend and pymongo, but only in my tests.

**Other investigation:**

I set up a little test construct to see if that is something related to my project or a general thing.

I created some modules:

*bar/bar.py*

```
import random

def do_some_other_something():
    return random.choice([10])
```

*foo/foo.py*

```
import random
from bar.bar import do_some_other_something

def do_something():
    return random.choice([1])

def do_something_else():
    return do_some_other_something()
```

And a test case:

```
from foo.foo import do_something, do_something_else
from unittest import mock

assert(do_something() == 1) # check
assert(do_something_else() == 10) # check

with mock.patch("foo.foo.random.choice") as mock_random_choice:
    assert (do_something() != 1) # check (mocked as expected)
    assert (do_something_else() == 10) # assertion! also mocked
```

So I am really confused about this. I explicitly mocked foo.foo's random.choice not bar.bar's. So why is that happening? Intended? Is there a way to fix that?

Thank you!

Comment: `foo.foo` and `bar.bar` don't have different `random.choice`s.

Comment: That's exactly what I figured, but the interesting thing about this is, if you read the instructions in "Where To Patch" it explicitly tells you define the module under test inside of your path to the module you want to patch. 
But somehow this is not taken into account in this case, why?

Comment: Your situation is more like the last paragraph of "where to patch", where it says if module `b` does `import a` and uses `a.SomeClass`, then you should patch `a.SomeClass` (not `b.a.SomeClass`). That would be a global change, though. There's nothing in the "where to patch" examples where you only want to mock one module's use of another module and leave all other uses unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's only one `random` module in the program. When `foo.foo` and `bar.bar` both `import random`, they **share** the `random` module. Patching the `choice` function on the `random` module modifies the one `random` module used by every part of the program, including both `foo.foo` and `bar.bar`.

Instead of patching `foo.foo.random.choice`, patch `foo.foo.random`. That replaces `foo.foo`'s reference to the `random` module, but not `bar.bar`'s reference. `bar.bar` will continue to access the real `random` module, but `foo.foo` will see a mock `random`.

Comment: Got it now! Thanks for taking the time explaining it to me.