# Why is the pytest mocker patching module methods globally (depending on the modules import)?

Tags: python, import, scope, mocking, patch

#### Problem:

For testing, I want to patch `time.sleep` in my main module (and assert its call), *without* patching it in submodules.
However, importing `time` in my modules and patching `time.sleep` in my main module (`mocker.patch("main.time.sleep")`) mocks `time.sleep` in *all* submodules as well (Scenario A).
Concurrently, importing `sleep` from `time` and patching `sleep` in my main module (`mocker.patch("main.sleep")`) mocks `sleep` *only* in the main module (Scenario B, desired result).

#### Questions

Why is that? Why does the import make a difference? Why is `time.sleep` mocked globally in the first place? Shouldn't it be mocked only where it is looked up?

#### Thoughts

According to unittests [Where-To-Patch-Article](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) "patch() works by (temporarily) changing the object that a name points to with another one".
→ So the method `sleep` in `time` should be replaced for all modules in both scenarios?

Also, "you patch where an object is looked up, which is not necessarily the same place as where it is defined".
→ So maybe the `sleep` method is *not* replaced for all modules?

The article also states for a main module `b`:

- if `SomeClass`  is imported from module `a` and `SomeClass()` is called in main module `b` → `SomeClass` is looked up in main module `b`
- if module `a` is imported and `a.SomeClass()` is called in main module `b` → `SomeClass` is looked up in module `a`

  → Is that the reason, why `sleep` is mocked globally in scenario A and locally in scenario B? But isn't `sleep` in both scenarios just a reference to the very same `time.sleep` method?

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593427/python-mock-patch-patches-a-used-module-for-submodule-under-test-and-every-other) discussion, importing (eg) `time` in different modules means *sharing* the `time` module. And patching a method of it in the main module patches it for all other modules as well. Whereas patching the whole `time` module in main would solely change the *reference* of `time` in main.
→ I am confused. Why so? When are we having references, when are we sharing modules, when are we mocking globally, when are we mocking locally and what is the logic behind all that?

#### Setup (Not working, Scenario A):

main.py:

```
import time
import module

def sleep_in_main():
    time.sleep(1)  # this is mocked
    module.sleep_in_module()
```

module.py:

```
import time

def sleep_in_module():
    time.sleep(1)  # this is also mocked
```

test.py:

```
import main

def test(mocker):
    sleep_mock = mocker.patch("main.time.sleep")
    main.sleep_in_main()
    assert sleep_mock.call_count == 1  # fails (is called twice)
```

#### Setup (Working, Scenario B):

main.py:

```
from time import sleep
import module

def sleep_in_main():
    sleep(1)  # this is mocked
    module.sleep_in_module()
```

module.py:

```
from time import sleep

def sleep_in_module():
    sleep(1)  # this is not mocked
```

test.py:

```
import main

def test(mocker):
    sleep_mock = mocker.patch("main.sleep")
    main.sleep_in_main()
    assert sleep_mock.call_count == 1  # passes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is how the python/mocking framework work.

When you do `import time` you essentially say: `import time as time` in your module, which is like defining an attribute: `time = reference to time module`.

Later, when you define `sleep_in_main` method, you add another attribute `sleep_in_main = reference to method body`.

If however you do `from time import sleep` you essentially define `sleep = reference to sleep from time module`.

Now, all mocking does is replace the attribute, so if you do `mocker.patch("main.sleep")` it means `sleep = MagicMock()` for your main module. It doesn't affect the other modules since it touches the sleep attribute of the main module.

If you do `mocker.patch("main.time.sleep")` the mock looks up `main.time`, which is a reference to the time module, then it accesses the sleep attribute from that reference, but that sleep is defined in the time module, so it does `sleep = MagicMock()` in the time module itself, which affects all the modules importing it.

This reference/attribute game is similar to what happens to function parameters. Say this is your code:

```
def f1(p):
    p.append(3)

def f2(p):
    p = [5]

a = [1, 2]

f1(a)
f2(a)
```

The value of `a` would be `[1, 2, 3]`, since the f1 is referring a and changing it, while f2 repoints the variable p to an entirely different list.

Hope this makes sense.